# Xamarin In App Billing Plugin could not connect

Tags: android, xamarin, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have used this plugin: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin to implement the in app billing since the component was removed.
I have installed the nuget: Plugin.InAppBilling

In the Android, I have create a class called InAppBillingService where I implement here to get the products and purchase an item. Here are the codes:

```
var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync();
```

And it returns false everytime. I could not connect.

I have added in my AndroidManifest this:

```
uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

And in the MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            InAppBillingImplementation.HandleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

And in onCreate: `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);`

Please advice what else I should do so that I could connect. And what are other reasons why it always return false when tried to connect. I'm testing in emulator. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I can browse apps in Play Store in the emulator through the browser. It doesn't have "Play Store" installed. And it has internet access

Comment: do you have an idea how to install google play store in the emulator? I have used Emulator in VS 2017 for android

Comment: I have now installed the google play store and still could not connect.

Comment: Try your code on a physical device to confirm whether your emulator is configured properly or it is the code at this point.

Comment: Have you tried testing in emulator before? I checked it here: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/TestingAndTroubleshooting.html but it said emulator will not work

Comment: In production images (I think they are called "Google Play Store images") it should work fine assuming you have not rooted the image as we have tested wi/ them. In all the other emulator images it will not work as they are not "verified"  and the base images do not include the Play Store APIs plus are rooted, in that case you need a physical device to test with.

Comment: I just switch to test in my device and I was able to connect and get the products and when I do a purchase an item, during the call to connect to Play store, it takes a very long time then it crashes the app. You have an idea why it happened?

Comment: During my first call, I did call this await billing.DisconnectAsync(); at then end

Comment: Hello. Im able to work it now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm testing in emulator.

That's the reason of the problem. As written [here](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/TestingAndTroubleshooting.html), Billing does not work on Android emulators. Use a real device.